# How do I place the three vertical android dots wherever I want within my app, but will still trigger the menu?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building an android game that doesn't have an action bar. Even though I don't have an action bar, I still want the three vertical dots placed somewhere within my app. I'm not sure if I have to create my own image file that contains the dots, or if there's some way to move the dots in the layout manager in eclipse. Then when these dots are selected I want it to do the vertical drop down menu option like it does in the action bar.

Also I want the dots to disappear in android phones running under android 4.0, so that they can just use the normal menu button. Is this possible? It would be even better if I could get the three dots to trigger the menu in phones below 4.0 but I don't think that's possible so I'd rather just hide it entirely.

Thanks.

Comment: if you want it to act like the ationbar menu why not just use the actionbar

Comment: Because I want the game to have a certain look, and I don't want the actionbar to be in it. I just want the vertical dots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure if I have to create my own image file that contains the dots

The standard overflow icon should be in your SDK.

> or if there's some way to move the dots in the layout manager in eclipse

No.

> Then when these dots are selected I want it to do the vertical drop down menu option like it does in the action bar.

You are welcome to implement your own `PopupMenu` for displaying a menu.

> Also I want the dots to disappear in android phones running under android 4.0, so that they can just use the normal menu button

You are welcome to call `setVisibility()` on whatever you are using for your image whenever the mood strikes you. You will also need to arrange to display your own menu for MENU button presses.

IOW, you will need to roll your own menu system: displaying your trigger, displaying the menu based on the trigger, and doing something on menu choice selections. You are welcome to crib bits of this from the AppCompat action bar in the Android Support package, or perhaps ActionBarSherlock, if you wish.

> It would be even better if I could get the three dots to trigger the menu in phones below 4.0

Since you are writing it all yourself, you are welcome to have it do whatever you want.